# Mysql Server Connect Issue in SQLYOG

Tags: mysql, sqlyog

is there any way to connect to a remote database by using SQLyog? I have the ip address, user name and password of the database. However, I have 'Error 2003 - Can't connect to MySQL server on '[myIpAddress]' (10035) whenever I test connection in SQLyog.

Comment: Do you have SSH access try sqlyog with SSH connection

Comment: Yes solved it with SSH connection...Thanks For Reply

Answer (score 1):

Need to use both ssh connection and mysql server connection for establishment of successful connection.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add % wild card in your cpanel to enable mysql remote connection, if you cannot do this, you can use SSH tunnel to connect to database, Please check the following screenshot

[image]

[image]